# AngularJS - dynamic generated ng-model-name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I try and try but I cant get it working.. I do a ng-repeat creates me some DIVs out of a $scope-object:

```
<div class="col-2 currBit" ng-repeat="one in crypto">
                <div class="currBitTitle">{{one.shortName}}</div>                    
                <div class="currBitTitleSub">
                    <div class="currLogo currLogo_{{one.shortName}}"></div><br/>
                    {{one.longName}}<br/>                        
                </div>
                <div class="currBitInput">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Your amount of {{one.shortName}}" ng-model="one.shortName" >
                </div>
            </div>
```

now, in the inputfield of each created DIV I need to set a ng-model, so my app can use the input-vlaues of the dynamicly generated input-fields

in this code posted, when the data is bound to the `<div class="currBitTitle">{{one.shortName}}</div>` ?? .. why is that? How can I get this managed?

it would be nice to have a individual prefix like `ng-model="myfoobar_{one.shortName}"`

is that even possible?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. What exactly do you want to do with your input fields? (_Also,_ `{{one.shortName}}` _is the same as_ `ng-model="one.shortName"`)

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey .. ok thx, I have edited the question, I hope it is now clearer what I want do achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use like below code also check this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/DrQ77/1056/) link for your example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myfoobar_[one.shortName]">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.myfoobar_ = {};
$scope.crypto = [{
   "shortName": "Name1",
   "longName": "Name One"
}, {
   "shortName": "Name2",
   "longName": "Name Two"
}];
```

Comment: thank you very much.. this makes sense.. I have seen such a example in a other context, but now I understand... many thanks ;)